# Как найти разность всех элементов массива с помощью цикла while?

Tags: c#

нужно найти разность элементов массива при помощи цикла while. Я нашёл сумму элементов, но я не очень понимаю, как найти разность:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] array = new int[15];

            Console.WriteLine("Заполните данные(15 чисел):");

            for(var i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            {
                array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
            }

            int result1 = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                result1 = result1 + array[i];
            }
            Console.WriteLine(result1);


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инициализируйте переменную result1 значением нулевого элемента из array. Затем в цикле от 1 до array.Length просто вычитайте:

```
for (var i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
    result1 -= array[i];
```

Итого:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int size = 5;
    int[] array = new int[size];
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
        array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int result1 = array[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
        result1 -= array[i];
    Console.WriteLine(result1);
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Только один момент - вы забыли про цикл while.

Comment: @НикитаРассоха, рад помочь ! :)

Comment: @CasperSC , да, конечно без цикла while, но оно работает - и хорошо. Я просто пока только начинаю изучать c#, да и программирование в целом, так что мне сойдёт.

Comment: @CasperSC , я так сам прикинул, как это с циклом while - и вроде получилось: 

int g = 1;
int result3 = array[0];
            while (g < array.Length)
            {
                result3 -= array[g];
                g++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(result3);

            Console.ReadLine();

Comment: @НикитаРассоха, да это всё понятно. Мне вообще по большому счёту без разницы, хоть там был бы ответ на другой вопрос. Я просто заметил, что ответ не совсем соответствует поставленному вопросу. Всегда лучше, если он ему соответствует.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть так?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // ...

    Console.WriteLine("Заполните данные(15 чисел):");

    for(var i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
    }

    int result1 = array[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        result1 = result1 - array[i];
    }
    Console.WriteLine(result1);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Вы немного запутались - Вы используете индекс i вне цикла for.

Comment: @isnullxbh Имелось  в виду 0, спасибо.